# Selenium ChromeDriver exception after upgrading chrome to version 63

Tags: c#, selenium

We have an automated Selenium solution for some routine works on an admin panel. It was working until yesterday suddenly it broke. Navigation is fine:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); // this works just fine
```

However, this line breaks:

```
var inputs = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input"));
```

And the exception message is:

```
Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2110
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<CssSelector>b__1c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
```

I have no idea what is the reason of this problem. Since version 63 of Chrome is forcing HSTS, I thought maybe there is something wrong with `chromedriver.exe` because of huge changes in Chrome 63. Please help.

Comment: What is the version of your chromedriver.exe?

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: Run it in cmd. And I think you should uodate it to 2.34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suit's comment appears to be correct (thank you). I had the latest WebDriver nuget packages installed, but not the latest chromedriver.exe. Version 2.34 has fixed it.

[ChromeDriver Download Page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)